# Crear carpeta con Java en la ruta C:\Program Files

Tags: java, archivo

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicación en Java y necesito crear una carpeta y dentro un fichero txt.
Esa carpeta me gustaría que estuviera en la ruta C:\Program Files\MiCarpeta para evitar que el usuario la tenga desordenada. Pero me veo con el problema de que necesito permisos de administrador para escribir en C:\Program Files y esto no funciona.

```
File directorios = new File("C:\\Program Files\\MiCarpeta");
    if (!directorios.exists()) {
        if (directorios.mkdir()) {
            System.out.println("Multiples directorios fueron creados");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error al crear directorios");
        }
    }
```

Luego al intentar crear el fichero utilizo lo siguiente que tampoco funciona.

```
ObjectOutputStream saida = null;

                try {

                    saida = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Program Files\\MiCarpeta\\datos.txt"));

                    saida.writeObject(u);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("ERRO: Problemas co ficheiro2");
                }
```

Me gustaría saber como puedo crear la carpeta en esa ruta si es posible y crear el fichero y si luego tendría problemas a la hora de leerlo, si no es posible crearlo en esa ruta me gustaría saber como puedo utilizar java para crear la carpeta en C:\Users\UsuariodelPC\MiCarpeta ya que UsuariodelPC es diferente en cada ordenador. Gracias

Comment: Buenas, si no tienes permisos de escritura en ninguna de las carpetas de Program Files , no podras ejecutar tu código funcional, primeramente  deberias  elevar privilegios de administrador manualmente y darle permisos de lectura, escritura, y modificación a la carpeta que necesites. Luego de esto intenta  ejecutar nuevamente tu código. Esta referencia puede ayudar: https://norfipc.com/utiles/como-administrar-cambiar-permisos-archivos-carpetas-windows.html

Comment: Gracias por responder. La idea es que al distribuir el jar el usuario final no tenga que modificar los permisos de C:\program files , me gustaría que desde la aplicación java se pidiera al usuario que un programa necesita permisos de administrador y apareciera ese popup de windows y que el usuario pudiera aceptar o denegar. No se si sería posible? Otra opcion es ejecutar el jar con permisos de administrador, pero no me acaba de gustar esa opcion

Comment: Podrías mirar este enlace si te puede ayudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935829/can-not-change-permission-of-folder-through-java-code